# Changed data for a key in Redis: how to figure out what changed it

Tags: redis

The web application I am working with is written in `Django` and is using `Redis` to cache some data from `Elasticsearch`. Yesterday everything was working fine, but today it started to give me an error. I looked over the structure of the data `redis` is storing for the key and some of the deep inner values for keys were changed to `lists` instead of `dicts` (that they are supposed to be). So, overnight `redis` data was modified by someone or something. Now I need a way to figure out which code changed it. If I launch the app after doing `redic-cli flushdb` and start using it, navigating here and there everything is working fine, and I can't find any apparent wrong code this way. The data for `redis` is set only in one place in the app code and it is set correctly. I looked into `redis.log` but it does not say which key it modified and when but this data could be crucial here.

So, I need to find out which code mistakenly modified the key. It could be separately run code by someone, could be some hidden specific side of the app (I doubt it is the case), or some bug within the `redis` itself. Maybe I would need to introduce some kind of additional observer that would run each time keys are changed writing when and which key was modified in `redis`. I am stuck and not sure what I could do here. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The easiest way could be to check the contents of the key that has a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things you may try with Redis:

[`MONITOR`](https://redis.io/commands/monitor) is a debugging command that streams back every command processed by the Redis server. You may then see what command is modifying your key, from what client connection.

[Redis Keyspace Notifications](https://redis.io/topics/notifications) allow you to subscribe to Pub/Sub channels in order to receive events affecting the Redis data set in some way. You can subscribe to the key of interest.

[`CLIENT LIST`](https://redis.io/commands/client-list) command returns information and statistics about the client connections server in a mostly human readable format.

As you are suspicious from another code or someone modifying your data, you may want to use Redis 6 with [ACLs](https://redis.io/topics/acl), to control what clients can do what operations on what keys.